# iOS - Tackling Syncing with MySql

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, synchronization

I am wanting to learn about syncing data in my iPhone app with my MySql database.

I have nto done to much reading up on it yet, as it is pretty hard to find concrete information on it.

What is the best route to explore for this?
Do I go down this route? [ASIHTTPRequest Setup Instructions](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)

My Question really is, where do I go to find out about this. I appreciate it is a big topic and I don't really want to go down a wrong route thinking it is the right one.

Any hints and tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a REST interface for the server that will host the MySQL database, and RestKit with CoreData support (Managed Object Loader) on iOS.

But this is really a very broad question, and the answer depends on a lot of factors (availability of skills and tools, access to server, taste, philosophy, size of project, accuracy and timeliness of synchronization).